Webpack does not bundle a package imported by an imported package
I have a project that uses Webpack.
This project uses package A that exposes a single file index.js.
In that file there's an import from @mui/material/styles. @mui/material is listed as a peer dependency of package A.
When I import package A in my project I get an error: @mui/material/styles can't be found. If I do something like this directly in the project import {} from "@mui/material/styles" the error disappears and everything works.
What can be the problem here? How can I debug this issue using stats?
I tried debugging this issue by emitting a stats.json file from Webpack, but had limited success.
